# PagerAdapter does not call get item after recreate the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, state, appcompatactivity

I have a button to recreate the activity, which call:

```
recreate();
```

This is the code at the activity **onCreate**, the activity is a viewpager with different fragment inside that, base on the return position will assign the different data on that , in fact it runs after recreate:

```
    if (app.cat == null) {
        app.cat = new ArrayList<Category>();

        Ion.with(ctx)
                .load(app.API + "api/shop/category-list")
                .setBodyParameter("lang", MyApp.lang)
                .setBodyParameter("device_token", app.token)
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        String status = result.get("result").getAsString();

                        if (status.equals("OK")) {
                            JsonArray cat_list = result.get("categories").getAsJsonArray();

                            for(int i = 0; i < cat_list.size(); i++) {
                                JsonObject cat_obj = cat_list.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                                app.cat.add(new Category(cat_obj.get("id").getAsString(), cat_obj.get("label_name").getAsString(), cat_obj.get("label_name_en").getAsString(), cat_obj.get("img").getAsString()));
                            }

                            setupPager();
                        } else if (result.get("error_code").equals("666")) {
                            createErrorBox(result.get("message").getAsString());
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, result.get("message").getAsString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    } else {
        setupPager();
    }
}
```

Call `setupPager()` after the data is ready:

```
private void setupPager () {
    view_pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            tab_layout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

            SampleFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), ctx, app);

            view_pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

            tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(view_pager);
            tab_layout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

            for (int i = 0; i < tab_layout.getTabCount(); i++) {
                TabLayout.Tab tab = tab_layout.getTabAt(i);
                if (tab != null) {
                    tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
                }
            }

            //view_pager.setCurrentItem(1);
            tab_layout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
}
```

And the problem is , even though it has setup the pager again after re-create, the pager adapter does not call the `getitem()` and does not return the position

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private MyApp app;
    private Context context;

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        tv.setText(app.cat.get(position).name);
        return v;
    }

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context _context, MyApp _app) {
        super(fm);
        context = _context;
        app = _app;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return app.cat.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        **//does not call after recreate**

        PageFragment p = new PageFragment();
        p.setID(app.cat.get(position).id);
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return app.cat.get(position).name;
    }
}
```

And finally , the fragment itself

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    private String id;
    private MyApp app;
    private Context ctx;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private ArrayList<Product> products;

    public PageFragment () {
    }

    public void setID (String _id) {
        id = _id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ctx = getContext();
        app = (MyApp) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, container, false);

        rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        if (app.product == null) {
            app.product = new HashMap<>();
        }

        **// id is null after re-create**
        products = app.product.get(id);

        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(products, ctx, app);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4));

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: check that `app.cat` is not empty!

Comment: yes checked at main activity, see update question, thanks  a lot

Comment: post code, where you re-create

Comment: Also at main activity , it is at menu to recreate view when change locale will post later